# Strong Markov Property for random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I have a problem, let $S_n$ process such that $ S_n := \xi_1 + \dots + \xi_n$ and stoping time moment $\tau: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup{\infty}$, where

\begin{equation*}
\xi = 
\begin{cases}
1 & p \\
-1 & 1 - p
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I need to prove that $X_n = S_{n + \tau} - S_\tau$ has the same distribution like $S_n$ and independed of sigma algebra $\mathcal{F_\tau}$ and satisfies $X = S$ in distribution.

I know these facts are true for brownian motion by strong markov property, so I try to extend this theorem to this discrete case.

Can anyone tell me which direction I should go? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Repeat the proof of what you did in Brownian Motion. Otherwise, read a book on basics of discrete time markov chains (eg Norris) and see the proof for general discrete time markov chains.